# rsync and torsocks error: connection refused (111) and error in socket IO (code 10)

Tags: proxy, rsync, tor, connection-refused, torsocks

I wanted to download some files from tor (.onion site) with rsync and torsocks with this command (I'm on Linux):

```
torsocks rsync rsync://root@snatchvwddns6zto.onion/targets/perceptics.com/
```

and it returns back the error:

```
1560930992 PERROR torsocks[13894]: socks5 libc connect: Connection refused (in socks5_connect() at socks5.c:202)
rsync: failed to connect to snatchvwddns6zto.onion (127.42.42.0): Connection refused (111)
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at clientserver.c(127) [Receiver=3.1.3]
```

And the onion site `snatchvwddns6zto.onion/targets/perceptics.com/` is fully functional

Already changed the port of the torsocks.conf file to the same port that tor is already on (9051) and still didn't work.
Even when trying to authenticate:

```
echo -e 'AUTHENTICATE "passwordhere"\r\nsignal NEWNYM\r\nQUIT' | nc 127.0.0.1 9051
```

it returns:

```
(UNKNOWN) [127.0.0.1] 9051 (?) : Connection refused
```

torsocks.conf:

```
TorAddress 127.0.0.1
TorPort 9150
```

Does someone know how to solve does errors?

Comment: `torsocks rsync -avzr rsync://root@snatchvwddns6zto.onion:/perceptics.com .`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also expose the SSH port instead of the rsync one and do something like:

```
torify rsync -e "ssh -p 9051" root@snatchvwddns6zto.onion:targets/perceptics.com/ ./
```